# Is there a way in Apache Camel by which a lock can be obtained and released by a route on another route

Tags: apache-camel

I am looking out for a way by which a route can obtain and release a lock on another route, Below is my code snippet and I am looking for a solution where snmp-trap-route and snmp-timer-route can obtain an exclusive lock on business-logic-route and while one is processing other should wait till it completion.

```
<route id="snmp-trap-route">
<from uri="snmp:{{snmp.host}}:{{snmp.port}}?protocol=udp&amp;type=TRAP" />
<to uri="direct:snmp-main-route"/>
```

```
<route id="snmp-timer-route">
<from uri="timer://pulse?fixedRate=true&amp;period=1000" />
<to uri="direct:snmp-main-route"/>
```

```
<route id="snmp-main-route">
        <from uri="direct:snmp-main-route" />
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <simple>${property[batch.ended]} == true </simple>                      
                    <to uri="direct:transacted-endpoint" />
                </when>
                <when>
                    <simple>${property[batch.started]} == true </simple>                        
                    <to uri="direct:business-logic-endpoint" />
                </when>
                <otherwise>                 
                    <to uri="direct:business-logic-endpoint" />
                </otherwise>
            </choice>               
    </route>

<route id="business-logic-route">
        <from uri="direct:business-logic-endpoint"/>
        <setProperty propertyName="route.name">
            <constant>TestRoute</constant>
        </setProperty>
        <process ref="messageMultiplierProcessor" />
        <process ref="calculatedFieldsProcessor" />
        <process ref="tableProcessor" />                        
    </route>

<route id="transacted-route">
        <from uri="direct:transacted-endpoint"/>
        <transacted/>
        <to uri="direct:business-logic-endpoint"/>
        <onException>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <handled>
                <constant>true</constant>
            </handled>
            <rollback markRollbackOnly="true"/>
        </onException>
    </route>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reach the same result by using a queue.

A queue processes the messages 1-by-1. You can use the Seda component to achieve this if your route is in the same camelcontext. Otherwise you can use activemq

```
<route id="snmp-trap-route">
<from uri="snmp:{{snmp.host}}:{{snmp.port}}?protocol=udp&amp;type=TRAP" />
<to uri="seda:business-logic-route"/>

<route id="snmp-timer-route">
<from uri="timer://pulse?fixedRate=true&amp;period=1000" />
<to uri="seda:business-logic-route"/>

<route id="business-logic-route">
<from uri="seda:business-logic-endpoint"/>            
<setProperty propertyName="esq.route.name">
    <constant>TestRoute</constant>
</setProperty>
<process ref="messageMultiplierProcessor" />
<process ref="calculatedFieldsProcessor" />
```

This way the next message in the `business-logic-route` will only be processed after the `business-logic-route` is finished. Maybe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Ewout- Thanks for your reply, but it's not working in my case due to asynchronous behaviour of seda as consumers are invoked in a separate thread from the producer, also I had edited my question to show the complete camel context

Comment: My mistake, I tried out in a different way by which It wasn't working as expected, it worked now..thanks for your help